# Lookup function of Hash Table in SML

Tags: hashtable, lookup, sml

I was given an assignment to write a lookup function for this hashtable datatype in SML;

```
datatype 'a ht = table of (int * ('a list)) list;
```

which returns nil if the table is empty and/or the key doesn't exist the table.
The function is supposed to be this

```
val lookup = fn : int -> 'a ht -> 'a list
```

but i don't know how to look in each bucket of a hashtable or to display the value of the bucket of the key. I would appreciate some help on what kind of an algorithm to use.

for example the function should work like this;

```
-lookup 3 (table [(1, [2,3]), (2, [3,4,5]), (3, [4])]);
  val it = [4] : int list
-lookup 4 (table [(1, [2,3]), (2, [3,4,5]), (3, [4])]);
  val it = [] : int list
```

Comment: I've tried to use a find function to simplify it which is;        
 fun find key nil = false | find key (x::rest) = if key = x then true else find key (rest); 
 but apparently this is for a list and doesn't accept a hashtable type.
 I am looking for a way to apply this to a hashtable.
 and then somehow printing the value of the key if it exists.

Comment: first write a function that finds an int in an int list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hash table is a list of pairs.

for fun lookup n table = ...
First you will need a function to travel down the list of pairs to the nth position.
you could use something like

```
case table of
table [] => nil
|table ls => lookup n-1 table (tl ls)
```

Second get the value (#2 of the pair) or by pattern matching when the second argument of your lookup function is reduced to 1 in the recursion, assuming your keys are ranked in order like in your examples.
Then just return it.